# Increase thickness of createCompoundBorder

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to get the lines to match the height(yAxis) to the title in the center of the compound border. Here is an image to help explain a bit on what I'm looking for (only not as far as the arrows actually point)...

[image]

And here is the code...

```
package Main;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

/**
 * Created by Vako on 4/16/2017.
 */
public class TestGui extends JFrame {
    private final String[] guiCharSelDefault = {"---  Select Character ---"};
    private final String[] characters = {"charOne", "charTwo", "charThree", "charFour"};
    private final String[] GuiCharSel = (String[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(guiCharSelDefault, characters);
    private final String[] weapon = {"Weapon"};
    private final String[][] allWeapons = {
            {
                    "weakWeaponOne", "strongWeaponOne", "shortWeaponOne", "longWeaponOne"
            },
            {
                    "weakWeaponTwo", "strongWeaponTwo", "shortWeaponTwo", "longWeaponTwo"
            },
            {
                    "weakWeaponThree", "strongWeaponThree", "shortWeaponThree", "longWeaponThree"
            },
            {
                    "weakWeaponFour", "strongWeaponFour", "shortWeaponFour", "longWeaponFour"
            }
    };
    private JComboBox charCombo = new JComboBox(GuiCharSel);
    private JComboBox weaponsCombo = new JComboBox(weapon);
    private JPanel centerFrame = createCenterFrame();

    //**************************************************************************************

    private GridBagConstraints setGbc(int gridx, int gridy, int ipadx, int ipady, String anchorLocation, double weightx, double weighty, Insets insets){
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("NORTHWEST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("NORTH")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("NORTHEAST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("WEST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("EAST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("SOUTHWEST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("SOUTH")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("SOUTHEAST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST;
        } else {
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        }

        gbc.gridx = gridx;
        gbc.gridy = gridy;
        gbc.ipadx = ipadx;
        gbc.ipady = ipady;
        gbc.weightx = weightx;
        gbc.weighty = weighty;
        gbc.insets = insets;

        return gbc;
    }

    private Insets setInsets(int top, int left, int bottom, int right){
        Insets insets = new Insets(top,left,bottom,right);
        return insets;
    }

    //**************************************************************************************

    private JPanel createCenterFrame(){
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
        Border raisedBevel = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
        Border loweredBevel = BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder();
        Border compound = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(raisedBevel, loweredBevel);
        TitledBorder topFrameTitle = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(compound, "Character");
        topFrameTitle.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.CENTER);

        pnl.setBorder(topFrameTitle);

        charCombo.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        String charName = ((JComboBox)(e.getSource())).getSelectedItem().toString();
                        if (charName.equals("charOne")){
                            weaponsCombo.removeAllItems();
                            weaponsCombo.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(allWeapons[1]));
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
        pnl.add(charCombo, setGbc(0,0, 0, 0, "NORTHWEST", 0, 0, setInsets(0, 10, 0, 0)));
        pnl.add(weaponsCombo, setGbc(0,0, 0, 0, "NORTHWEST", 0, 0, setInsets(0, 10, 0, 0)));

        return pnl;
    }

    TestGui(){
        add(centerFrame, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize(400,175);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    //**************************************************************************************

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestGui();
    }
}
```

If anyone has any idea how to do this I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible implementation using `MatteBorder`

[image: screenshot]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class TestGui2 extends JFrame {
  private static JPanel createCenterFrame() {
    Border raisedBevel = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
    Border lineBorder = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(10, 0, 0, 0, Color.GRAY.brighter());
    Border loweredBevel = BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder();
    Border compound1 = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(raisedBevel, lineBorder);
    Border compound2 = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(compound1, loweredBevel);
    TitledBorder topFrameTitle = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(compound2, "Character");
    topFrameTitle.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.CENTER);

    JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
    pnl.setBorder(topFrameTitle);
    return pnl;
  }
  TestGui2() {
    add(createCenterFrame(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setSize(400, 175);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new TestGui2());
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I didn't know you could keep stacking lines together.